# How to work out mechanical advantage of different arrangements of hydraulic cylinders

Tags: classical-mechanics, everyday-life

I'm hoping you can help as I've having real trouble wrapping my beleaguered brain around this. If this question is better asked on another SE just let me know. Apologies if it's a bit pedestrian ;)

I'm trying to work out how to calculate the mechanical advantage for a number of different brake setups on cars. These systems work with a simple master/slave hydraulic system. The only real complication comes in the configuration of the master cylinder.

There are 3 common types of master cylinder (simplified as best I can):

1. A single piston master cylinder feeding 2 slave cylinders.
2. A dual master cylinder setup with two discreet systems of a master and a slave connected by a bar at the input of the master cylinder (so the force applied is split between each discreet system equally).
3. A [tandem setup](http://www.gomog.com/allmorgan/MC1.jpg) where a single bore houses two cylinders in-line, each feeding a slave cylinder. The first piston has force exerted on it, and the second floating piston is moved by the pressure applied from the first piston.

If all the slave cylinders are equal (lets say 20mm), and the fluid is incompressible, what are the respective mechanical advantages of the following systems:

1. A single master cylinder of 10mm diameter, arranged as a single setup above.
2. Two master cylinders of 5mm diameter, arranged as a dual setup above.
3. A tandem master cylinder of 5mm diameter, arranged as a tandem setup above.

The first two I think I've got right. The mechanical advantage for number 1 should be 40:10 = 4:1. Number 2 should also be 4:1 (20:5).

**The Question**

Am I right in saying that the mechanical advantage of number 3 should be 4:1 as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that by a mechanical advantage you mean the ratio between the total force applied to all slave cylinders to the total force applied to all master cylinders, all three configuration have to be reviewed.

Taking into account that, in the static case (i.e., when nothing is moving), the pressure acting on all cylinders in contact with the same fluid is the same, the ratio of forces should be equal to the ratio of cylinder (or piston) areas, not cylinder diameters.

For instance, in the first configuration, the ratio between the combined area of the two slave cylinders and the area of the master cylinder and, therefore, the mechanical advantage, is $16:1$, not $4:1$.

In a tandem master cylinder, the pressure associated with both pistons is the same. This is because for the floating piston to be in balance, the pressure in front of it and behind it should be the same. Since, both pistons have the same diameter, the forces associated with them should be the same as well.

If you take this and the rule about the ratio into account, finding the mechanical advantage for the tandem configuration should not be difficult.

Comment: Ah, so you're right. Area, not diameter. If I've understood you correctly, the pressure produced by setup 2 and setup 3 should be equal for a given force, so the mechanical advantage/ratio should be the same (both actually 4:1 in this instance).

Comment: @Ynneadwraith Each 5mm master piston is pushing its own 20mm slave piston. What is the ratio of areas?

Comment: Ah, 16:1 for each. I think what was confusing me was that in the tandem setup the first 5mm master is also pushing on a second 5mm master. As the ratio is 1:1 there, would you simply see a 50/50 split of the force exerted on the first master cylinder between the two? Say, if you apply 1kg of force to the first master cylinder, would you see 0.5kg of force exerted on each master? I think you would now, but I'm open to being wrong!

Comment: @Ynneadwraith It would be still $1$kG of force for both pistons. This is because each piston has to be in balance and, for that, the force in front of the first piston (pushing back on it) has to be equal to the applied force behind it. The same with the second piston.

Comment: Ah interesting. So you apply 1kg of force on the first piston and the second piston also experiences 1kg of force? Does that also apply to the dual-master situation where two completely discreet systems are linked by a bar connecting the inputs. So 1kg of force is applied to the bar, each end of which is connected to a piston. Does each piston experience 1kg of force?

Comment: @Ynneadwraith In this case, each piston will experience just half. This is because, for the bar to be in balance, the sum of the forces from the two pistons pushing back on the bar has to be equal to the force applied to the bar.

Comment: Huh, interesting. Here's why my old head-physics model is good for most stuff but falls apart every now and again. So with 1kg of force applied to our dual setup with a 16:1 ratio, we get 8kg from each slave cylinder. With 1kg of force applied to our tandem setup with its 16:1 ratio we'd end up with 16kg from each slave cylinder. Have I got that right?

Comment: @Ynneadwraith Looks good to me.

Comment: Bugger, well all my maths are wrong then ;) back to the drawing board! Thanks for your help :)